# Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D0072 in Desktop Recorder

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i downloaded [this source code](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/satisharveti/enhanced-desktop-recorder-in-net-using-C-Sharp-and-windows-forms/) , i tried to run it but when i click start recording it crash ! , i wonder what make it crash and what to do to avoid any further error in this code?

DesktopEncoder.PrepareToEncode(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of blindly running other peoples code, please read their whole article:

> Prerequisites:
>
> In order to use this application, we require Media Player Encoder 9.

He even gives a download link.

**Edit:**

The error code says:

> 0xC00D0072
>
> NS_E_NO_SPECIFIED_DEVICE
>
> "No specified device driver is present."

It seems you are missing something important.

Comment: i don't have mic, i unchecked the Add Audio, but it does not save what i record after stop recording?